# Retrieve settings after app reinstall in android

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, uninstallation

I have an app which saves some settings using PreferenceManager. Later I uninstall the application and later want to retrieve the same settings back when I reinstall the same application.
For eg: I have a checkbox whose state is saved using preference manager and later uninstall the app. Later when I reinstall the app I need to get the state back of that checkbox.
Is this possible to do?
If not with preferenceManager is there any other way to do it i.e by saving in DB?

Comment: The best option for this is really to store the information separately from the device. What if a user resets their device? Loses it and buys a new one? Sound like you'd want preferences to be kept then as well...

Comment: I wouldn't need it if user resets or replaces the phone. I need it only if the app is installed back in the same device as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a backup file for shared preferences in the external storage and when you install the application again you can update the shared preferences from the backup file. Or you can use `BackupAgentHelper/SharedPreferenceBackupHelper` to store the data on cloud.
For the `SQLite` however, if you keep the database files in a different directory those will not be removed by Android when uninstalling the application.
In case of a SQLite database you may set the database directory in the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor. Lets say you want the path set as:

```
final static String DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().concat("/databases/my_db.db");
```

Then in the sqlite helper you set it as follows:

```
public DbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, DB_PATH, factory, version);
}
```

Meanwhile in case of the SharedPreferences you may copy the file from the default app data directory to a folder of your chosen in the sd card. You need to pay attention here in order to choose the appropriate moment when to backup the SharedPreferences file. As a IO operation it might require time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference and Database won't be kept after uninstalling an app.
That being said, Android provides an easy way to send your SharedPreferences to the cloud and retrieve them when re-installing an app. This mechanism is called [BackupAgentHelper](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#BackupAgentHelper).

Comment: thats not true if the database files are stored not in the default app data directory

Comment: Sure, I was only speaking about internal **app specific** storage

Comment: By using external storage : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Can you give an example code of how to set the external path for databases.

Comment: The Android framework doesn't allow you to do it. But you can replicate data from the internal storage to the external storage